# Getting the share link for checkins from Foursquare API

Tags: api, foursquare, checkin

Currently I'm grabbing a user's latest checkin and displaying it on a page. This is done using an access token, e.g.

```
var url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins?oauth_token=" + access_token + "&v=20120214";
```

What I'm trying to do is have a link go to the check in URL on Foursquare, however that link asks for users to log in. The link is created like so:

foursquare.com/{username}/checkin/{checkinID}

This goes to a "log in to foursquare" page, but if I view the link for Twitter, it has an extra parameter, "s=", which shows the check in regardless of being logged into Foursquare or not.

So my question is how can I generate a share link for the check in? I can't find anything in the docs about having a signature, nor is it something I find in the checkin object.

Answer (score 1):

Check-ins are only visible to a user's friends, unless they choose to publish it to another system like Twitter or Facebook. Because of this, a potential viewer needs to log-in so we can verify that they are a friend of the user.